# How to give/add parent node for set of nodes in xmlDocument using vb.net or C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, xmldocument

How to add or give the parent node for set of nodes in xmlDocument using vb.net.

I am having following xml nodes

```
<books>
   <title>title</title>
   <isbn>123456</isbn>
   <surname>surname</surname>
   <givenname>givenname</givenname>
</books>
```

Now i want to add parent node `<author>` for `<surname>` and `<givenname>` as follows.

```
 <books>
   <title>title</title>
   <isbn>123456</isbn>
   <author>
      <surname>surname</surname>
      <givenname>givenname</givenname>
   </author>
 </books>
```

can any one tell me how to do it in xmlDocument in vb.net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to:

1. Get the parent node that you want to modify (books).
2. Add the new child element (author).
3. Get the child elements you want to move (surname and givenname).
4. For each node you want to move, remove it from it's parent node (books) and then add it as a child to the new parent node (author).

For instance:

```
Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
doc.Load(xmlFilePath)
Dim bookToModify As XmlNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("/books")
Dim author As XmlNode = doc.CreateElement("author")
bookToModify.AppendChild(author)
For Each node As XmlNode In bookToModify.SelectNodes("surname | givenname")
    node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node)
    author.AppendChild(node)
Next
```

Comment: The answer helped in guiding me. One point I would like to add is if you are looking for adding a new parent to the node for example the node variable in the above example. Then try creating a Parent node and add a clone of node. XmlNode newParent = newlycreatedparent.AppendChild(node.clone()) and then node.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(node,newParent)

Answer (score 1):

You can identify the nodes with a call to [`XPathSelectElements`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342176#Y600), then remove them from the tree and add them to a new `author` node.

---

**Example:**

```vb
Dim xml = <books>
            <title>title</title>
            <isbn>123456</isbn>
            <surname>surname</surname>
            <givenname>givenname</givenname>
          </books>

Dim author = <author />
xml.Add(author)
For Each node in xml.XPathSelectElements("./givenname|./surname")
    node.Remove()
    author.Add(node)
Next
```